# Remove Leading Zero(s) For Each Section Separated by '.' Except When '.0.'

Tags: leading-zero

In TSQL I need to create a script to remove all leading zero's between '.', starting with the first 0 in the string EXCEPT when there is a '.0.' anywhere in the middle of the task number.  What I have so far does fine when the task number does not have EX: 111.0.123.234, but I cannot seem to figure out the combination of SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX/PATINDEX, etc. to remove all leading zeros except when the zero is the only number between '.'   See attached screenshot and script/partial results as an example.

Here is my script:

```
SELECT TASKPRODUCTID, (CASE WHEN TASKPRODUCTID NOT LIKE '%.0.%' THEN
REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(TASKPRODUCTID,'0','')),' ','0') ELSE 
SUBSTRING(TASKPRODUCTID, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', TASKPRODUCTID + ' '),  LEN(TASKPRODUCTID))
END) AS NewTaskProductID
FROM TASK
```

Here is a partial resultset:

```
TASKPRODUCTID                        NewTaskProductID
003.007.002.001                      3.7.2.1
003.007.002.003                      3.7.2.3
004.003.003.008.0.2017275.132925     4.003.003.008.0.2017275.132925
004.005.001.003                      4.5.1.3
004.005.004.004.0.2017275.135139     4.005.004.004.0.2017275.135139
004.005.007.005.0.2017275.140304     4.005.007.005.0.2017275.140304
002.001.002                          2.1.2
002.004                              2.4
016.010                              16.1
```

[Screenshot Example of leading zero in highlighted rows still have leading zeros in next decimal section(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ34D.png)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **STUFF()** to get the .0. in the else case scenario

```
declare @s AS varchar(100) = '0010.0.005.006025'

print stuff(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(@s,'0','0')),'0','*'), 
 patindex('%.*.%',REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(@s,'0','0')),'0','*')), 3,'.-.')
```

OUTPUT

```
**1*.-.**5.**6*25
```

Now treat this as first scenario ; only difference is that we have got '*' instead of '0'

Comment: I will try this and see how I can edit to get to the desired result.  THANK YOU for taking time to at least respond and send me in a different direction!

Comment: @MarlaDeAnnHaase you can put the query once you get it done !!